# Shabbos Chol Hamoed - Mizmor L'David - Nusach Sefard

Tags: tefilla, yom-tov, nusach-sefard

Nusach Sefard usually says Mizmor L'David at the end of Maariv, Friday evenings, before Aleinu.

I have seen Shuls that skip this on Yom Tov that is on a Shabbos and on Shabbos Chol Hamoed. I have also seen Shuls that say it just like on a regular week.

Looking for sources either pro or con.

Comment: Pro: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-order-of-prayer-and-kiddush-when-yom-tov-coincides-with-shabbos/